# Visualising what is being removed from an array

Tags: java

Is there a way to visualise the current elements in an ArrayList before removing them?

clear() or removeall() unload all the elements instantly. Is it possible to return the elements before removing them?

```
public List<Obj o> clear() {

}
```

Comment: You could print all the elements just prior to removing them?

Comment: I guess so? Is there a method like pop() tho, one which returns the item and remove them? Or more specifically if I have a method public List<Obj xx> clear() {}

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to print all the items before you remove the items/elements. In this way, whatever you're asking for will be fulfilled easily.

Comment: That's a good way to go about it. However the question I'm looking at requires a return type

Comment: Could you clarify the context in a detailed way?

Comment: I think I've worked it out.

I could create a list to store all the removed objects and use a for loop to add them to the list every time I remove an object. And at the end I just need to return the list.

Answer (score 0):

The [official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) is always a great place to start. There is a method `remove(int)` that will remove the item at a particular index and return it to the caller.

You can remove whichever items you want (by index) and add them to a list that your method returns.